# Predicting Cellular Automata

Tags: cellular-automata

I am attempting to complete an assignment for an AI course however I cannot understand a question. Unfortunately, I cannot find any information on the internet that clearly explains how to predict the next generation in a CA. I have posted a link to a screenshot of my question below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVEm9.jpg)

Edit:

This is my edited answer;

[Edited Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdJQf.jpg)

Comment: This page should help: http://www.mirekw.com/ca/rullex_marg.html

Comment: @jdaz. Thank you for providing that link. However, I am still struggling to understand how to create the next generation.

Comment: @jdaz I have attempted to answer the question after re-reading the page however I would like to check if my answer was correct. I will be attempting to answer my question below

Answer (score 0):

In Margolus neighborhoods, the grid is divided into 2x2 blocks. Depending on which step you are in, the division of blocks either starts from the top-left corner or is offset one cell down and one cell to the right. (See Wikipedia on [Block cellular automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cellular_automaton).) Your instructions say to start from the top-left corner.

So you need to divide up the grid into 2x2 blocks. Then, you check how the patterns in each block match the [15 possible](http://psoup.math.wisc.edu/mcell/rullex_marg.html) Margolus neighborhood configurations:

[image: Margolus neighborhoods]

For the given grid, you end up with the following. The "neighborhoods" are labeled in yellow highlighted text:

[image: Divided grid]

Now you look at the rules you were given: MS, D 0; 14; 11; 5; etc. These numbers after the D tell you, in order, how each configuration should change.

- *0th number in rule (D **0**):* Counting from 0, the first number tells you how the `0` (empty) configuration should change. The given number is `0`, which means empty 2x2 blocks will not change in the next generation.
- *1st number in rule (D 0; **14**;):* The next number tells you how the `1` configuration (one X in upper left corner) should change. That number is `14`, which means if we have any 2x2 blocks with the `1` configuration, it should morph into the `14` block. We don't have any `1` configurations, so we go to the next number in the rule.
- *2nd number in rule (D 0; 14; **11**;):* The next number tells you how the `2` configuration should change, and that number is `11`. We have 2 blocks with the `2` configuration (one X in upper right corner), and the rule tells us we need to convert them to configuration `11` (2x2 block filled with X's except lower left corner).

After evaluating these first 3 rules, you end up with:

[image: Next generation]

Continue for the rest of the numbers in the rule and you will have your answer. As for whether the rule is reversible, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_cellular_automaton#Block_cellular_automata).

Comment: Should the boxes that are the same in the list all become blank in the next generation or remain the same?

Comment: They should stay the same. They would only become blank if the rule says they should become `0`.

Comment: Would you be able to check my corrected answer? I have completed the question.

Comment: @ jdaz I have included my corrected answer in my question.

Comment: Corrected answer looks good. Feel free to accept my answer if it was helpful to you.